# Geometric Network - Listening to network feature connection changes in the IObjectClassEvents::OnChange event

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, network, classextensions, geometric-network

I need to be able to tell when a particular type of feature, that participates in a geometric network, is having its geometry automatically modified due to the geometric network.

What i mean is that I'm currently listening to the IObjectClassEvents::OnChange and use it to work out if the feature being changed is of the type I am interested in and if the change is to its geometry. I use IFeatureChanges and IRowChanges. This works fine. However I also want to check if the change is caused by a change to a connected node in the geometric network OR if the change is due to the user modifying the feature directly.

Anyone have any idea how to do this ?

I would be looking for a INetworkFeatureChanges or an INetwokClassEvents interface, but they don't exist..

Thanks, 
Ian

Comment: Anyone?? I did find a turnaround but it's not pretty. In the OnChange Event, I use the IRowChanges and IFeatureChanges to determine if something change. If neither the row values nor the geometry has changed, I assume it's a geometric network action. I'm still waiting for a prettier way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making a lot of testing, I found that the most accurate way to detect geometric network actions(such as connect, disconnect) in an IObjectClassEvents::OnChange event is to use the interfaces IRowChanges and IFeatureChanges to determine if something changed.

```
    Private Function NetworkConnectivityChanged(ByVal obj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObject) As Boolean
        Return Not ValuesChanged(obj) And Not ShapeChanged(obj)
    End Function

    Private Function ValuesChanged(ByVal obj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObject) As Boolean
        Dim rowChanges As IRowChanges
        rowChanges = DirectCast(obj, IRowChanges)
        For i As Integer = 0 To obj.Fields.FieldCount - 1
            If rowChanges.ValueChanged(i) Then 
                Return True
            End If
        Next i

        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function ShapeChanged(ByVal obj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObject) As Boolean
        Dim featureChanges As IFeatureChanges
        featureChanges = DirectCast(obj, IFeatureChanges)
        Return featureChanges.ShapeChanged
    End Function
```

Comment: Interesting - so have you tested this by programmatically disconnecting something via [INetworkFeature.Disconnect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Disconnect_Method/0025000005m0000000/)?

Comment: Yes, I did, and the disconnect operation fired immmediatly the OnChange event. Same thing with the INetworkFeature.Connect event.